# Manter resultado do BD quando selecionar select com jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Tenho um form que mostra os linhas(departamentos) e as famílias(categorias) de produtos.
Estou tentando melhorar o cadastro populando o combobox de famílias, assim que seleciona a linha, retornando as famílias que estão vinculadas a linha selecionada.
Consigo mostrar a div certinho quando é inclusão de produto, mas quando é para atualizar, o combobox de famílias não é exibido.

Segue meu código:

linhas.php

```
<?php
include '../url_seo.php';
include 'config/config.inc.php';
include "funcoes/conexao.php";

conecta();

$cd_itprod = '786454';

$query = "select * from ti_produtos where cd_itprod= '".$cd_itprod."'";
$resul = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$row   = mysql_fetch_object($resul);
$cd_linha   = $row->cd_linha;
$cd_familia = $row->cd_familia;
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Atualizando combos com jquery</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="<?= $url_seo; ?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cd_linha').change(function(){
            $('#familia').load('listaFamilias.php?cd_linha='+$('#cd_linha').val());
        });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Atualizando combos com jquery</h1>
    <label>cd_linha:</label>
    <select name="cd_linha" id="cd_linha">
        <?php 
        $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ti_linhas ORDER BY nm_linha");
        while($reg = mysql_fetch_object($rs)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $reg->cd_linha ?>"><?php echo $reg->nm_linha ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="familia"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

listaFamilias.php

```
<?php 
include '../url_seo.php';
include 'config/config.inc.php';
include "funcoes/conexao.php";

conecta();

$cd_linha = $_GET['cd_linha'];

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ti_familias WHERE cd_linha = '$cd_linha' ORDER BY nm_familia");

echo "<label>familias: </label><select name='familia'>";
while($reg = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
    echo "<option value='$reg->cd_familia'>$reg->nm_familia</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Como faço para que o combobox que está em listaFamilias.php já venha preenchido com os dados do banco?

Comment: `$('#familia').load` vai tentar colocar um novo select dentro do seu select, o que é inválido. Você vai precisar criar um elemento por fora do select para usar o .load. Ou no php emitir somente as options.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta @bfavaretto, mas não entendi.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, mostrando um combobox quando já existe a variável $cd_familia, se o usuário alterar, busca o combobox em listaFamilias.php e dá hide na div "com_familia":

```
<?php
include '../url_seo.php';
include 'config/config.inc.php';
include "funcoes/conexao.php";
include "funcoes/funcoes.php";

conecta();

$cd_itprod = '786454';
echo "produto: ".$cd_itprod."<br>";

$query = "select * from ti_produtos where cd_itprod= '".$cd_itprod."'";
$resul = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$row   = mysql_fetch_object($resul);
$cd_linha   = $row->cd_linha;
$cd_familia = $row->cd_familia;

echo "cd_linha: ".$cd_linha. " - ".ds_linha($cd_linha)." - cd_familia: ".$cd_familia." - ".ds_familia($cd_familia)."<br>";
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Atualizando combos com jquery</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="<?= $url_seo; ?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cd_linha').change(function(){
            $("#com_familia").hide();
            $('#familia').load('listaFamilias.php?cd_linha='+$('#cd_linha').val());
        });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Atualizando combos com jquery</h1>
    <label>cd_linha:</label>
    <?php 
    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ti_linhas ORDER BY nm_linha");
    ?>
    <select name="cd_linha" id="cd_linha">
    <?php 
        while($reg = mysql_fetch_object($rs)): 
            echo "<option value='".$reg->cd_linha."'".($cd_linha == $reg->cd_linha?"SELECTED":"").">".$reg->nm_linha." (cód: ".$reg->cd_linha.")";
        endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="com_familia">
    <?
    if(isset($cd_familia)):?>
        <?
        $queryg = "select * from ti_familias where cd_familia!='' order by nm_familia";
        echo "<label>familias: </label><select name='cd_familia'>";
        $resug  = mysql_query($queryg) or die (mysql_error());
        while($rowg = mysql_fetch_object($resug)):
            echo "<option value='".$rowg->cd_familia."'".($cd_familia == $rowg->cd_familia?"SELECTED":"").">".$rowg->nm_familia." (cod: ".$rowg->cd_familia." - Linha: ".ds_linha($rowg->cd_linha).")";
        endwhile;
        echo "</select>";
    endif;
    ?>
    </div>
    <div id="familia"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```